# Are .htaccess files required for EE install?

Tags: htaccess

I'm discussing with my sysadmin about whether to allow .htaccess files. I noticed all over the EE file tree there are .htaccess files to prohibit access to files, such as to system/user/config/config.php. But they also appear to have built-in direct-access controls, such as:

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

So, .htaccess files a good idea to have on? Using EE 4.3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `.htaccess` file is not needed for EE install. If you don't make `.htaccess` file then also EE will run. But, it is advisable to keep `.htaccess` file for **removing the index.php from URL, leverage browser caching** and **gzip compression**.

`.htaccess` files are used to override settings which is set in the apache configuration. If you don't want to change, then you don't need (and shouldn't have) an `.htaccess` file.

`.htaccess` files are specifically for people who don't have permission to root.

Comment: We've actually placed the index.php removal and gzip directives in httpd.conf, so in this case, it looks like we can get away with disabling .htaccess files (AllowOverride none). Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

htaccess is not needed, however, to remove the index.php from the url you'll need it
Also for setting cache control headers it's usefull as wel as for caching and gzip output/extraction